# Delegate method UIDocumentPickerViewController are not working on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

Delegate method are not working for UIDocumentPickerViewController

from upload action want to load document from simulator for uploading to other action...

```
func uploadFile(){

        let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF), String(kUTTypeImage), String(kUTTypeMovie), String(kUTTypeVideo), String(kUTTypePlainText), String(kUTTypeMP3)], in: .import)
        documentPickerController.delegate = self
        present(documentPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

On selected didPickDocumentPicker noting happening in swift 5.0

```
extension UIViewController: UIDocumentMenuDelegate,UIDocumentPickerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate
{

    public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard let myURL = urls.first else {
            return
        }
        print("import result : \(myURL)")
       let fileName =  urls.first?.lastPathComponent
        print(fileName)
//        self.loadUploadView(selectedFile: fileName!)
    }

    func documentMenu(_ documentMenu:UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        print("view was cancelled")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

For Device its working fine but for simulator its not working
else for iOS versions 13 its not working.
Device Version is 14
Simulator versions is 13.